# How do I make XTerm not use bold?

Tags: linux, xterm, ansi

I like using XTerm, I like its default "fixed" font, and I like using terminal colors rather than having a monochromatic terminal.

However, XTerm seems to insist on using a bold version of the font whenever it's displaying a bright color:

[image: screenshot]

I hate the bold version of the font, but I like the brightness. The man page seems to suggest that adding "`XTerm.VT100.boldMode:false`" to my `~/.Xresources` would disable this "feature", but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I've had it in there for months, so it's not a rebooting issue.

How can I force XTerm to always use the standard, non-bold version of the fixed font, even when it's displaying bright text?

Edit: Some have suggested putting "XTerm*boldMode: false" in my ~/.Xresources. That didn't help either. I've confirmed that the changes have taken effect with xrdb, though:

```
$ xrdb -query | grep boldMode 
XTerm*boldMode: false
```

If I run xprop and click an xterm, I get "`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xterm", "XTerm"`" .. so I'm definitely running real xterms.

BTW, this is just a plain-vanilla Ubuntu Intrepid box. If anyone else here is running the same, can you try running:

```
echo -e '#\e[1m#'
```

...and let me know whether the # on the right has a black pixel in the middle like the one on the left does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you set the same font for bold and normal font it might work.

I set the `fixed` font for both like:

```
xterm*font: fixed
xterm*boldFont: fixed
```

If you then do `xrdb -load` and start a new term it was back to not being bold :)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: Is it normal for `xrdb -load` to take a very long time? I've been waiting for at least 5 minutes with no activity, and according to `ps -e` it's still running.

Comment: @DaveKennedy Same issue here - does it ever finish?

Answer (score 13):

Setting `allowBoldFonts` property works for me

Add the following line in your `~/.Xresources`

```
XTerm*allowBoldFonts: false
```

Comment: This works even when you use XTerm*faceName :-)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, probably also because I am using XTerm*faceName

Comment: `boldMode` is about the *emulation* of bold style in a font that has none, whereas `allowBoldFonts` allows the use of a bold style available in the font.

Answer (score 5):

X resources aren't reloaded until you reload the X windowing system, and they aren't polled unless you restart the executable which is doing it. Try running

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

in your current session.  Then start another xterm.   The next time you start X (relogin or reboot) the resources should be read automatically.

Another thing to try is to use a wildcard to make sure that it is picking up the resource correctly.  Use

```
XTerm*boldMode: false
```

instead.

Yet another thing to check is that you are actually running `xterm` when you run a terminal process.  If not, you will need to change the fonts with a different resource.

Comment: It's actually been in there for months, so that's not the issue. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: edited to add more things that could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There's an XTerm resource specifically for this.  Perhaps it didn't exist when the question was originally asked?

```
XTerm*colorBDMode: true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an xterm bug:

> http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=347790

A temporary fix which works for me is to put the following cludgy fix at the end of your `.bashrc` file:

```
 echo -e "\e[1mA\e[2J\e[7mB\e[m\e[?5h\e[?5l"
 clear
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't help. I'm running XTerm(237), and that bug was fixed in XTerm(235). The echo statement didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I found it necessary (on Lucid Lynx) to create `~/.Xdefaults-$(hostname)`.  Omitting hostname made settings ineffective.  ba's matching of font and boldFont did the trick of eliminating bold.  `xfontsel` is a nice way to figure out what font to specify there.  You can also start an `xterm` with something like `xterm -font '-misc-fixed-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'` to test that your defaults are taking effect.

Answer (score 1):

On fontsel-based system try `xterm -fa Fixed`. On my machine this fixes bold fonts, albeit the rendering becomes slower.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the setting has taken effect:

```
xrdb -query | grep XTerm
```

If it is not in there, then you can force it to load:

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources
```

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xrdb) for more on this command.

Comment: It's actually been in there for months, so that's not the issue. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: You should check if it is loading anyway.  If it isn't, your window manager doesn't do resources correctly.